# How to connect to a websocket server using SocketIO and vite proxy?

Tags: python, vue.js, websocket, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I'm currently building a VueJS website that works with websockets, and I ran into an issue after adding a proxy for my websocket server (which uses Python|Flask)

Here's my proxy configuration (that works for the '/api') `vite.config.ts` :

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        host: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api',
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
            },
            '/ws': {
                target: 'ws://127.0.0.1:5000',
                ws: true,
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/ws/, '')
            }    
        }
    }
})
```

Here's the code I use to attempt a connection :

```js
// '/game' is the namespace I use.
const $socket = io('/ws/game', {
    path: '/websocket'
});
$socket.connect();
```

Here's my server-side python code (to initialize the websocket server with Flask-SocketIO) :

```py
socket = SocketIO(
    app, 
    path = '/websocket',
    cors_allowed_origins = '*'
)
```

There's no error showing up, I just don't get the usual "Connected" message.

Comment: In your vite.config.ts file, you set the path to '/websocket' when proxying the WebSocket server using Vite. However, when connecting to the server, you are passing path: '/websocket' to the io function. This means that the client-side code is attempting to connect to '/ws/game/websocket' instead of '/ws/game'.

Comment: But '/websocket' is the path I specified on the server side, what should I fix ?

Comment: The default path is '/socket.io' so even without it I'd still have '/ws/game/socket.io'

Comment: I can help more if you tell me the client and server socket library versions. Also can you check this thread? https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/302#issuecomment-426086713

Comment: Client : "socket.io-client": "^4.6.1" ; Server : "Flask-SocketIO==5.3.3" ; I checked the thread and still didn't succeed :(

Comment: I tried with the following code : ```const $socket = io(`http://${location.hostname}:5000/game`, {
    path: '/websocket'
});```.
It  works, but in order to make it work, I have to make the server accessible on 0.0.0.0, although I want it to stay local (as the app and the server will be running on the same server).